When I use cl.exe to compile, the result turns off my two moniters
I am making a macro for a game, and every time I press a key that enables the macro, both my laptop screen and my hdmi monitor turns off.
This only happens when I compile the code using cl.exe. When I use g++, it works perfectly fine. I wish to use cl.exe so my customers don't have to install mingw just to use the program.
I tried removing my auth, and commenting out features, but it simply keeps on happening.
The problem started after I added my auth, but even its removal does not remediate the problem.
// The code for my virtual keypresses (the main driver for my macro)
// Function to simulate key press
void PressKey(int key)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(key, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    input.ki.wVk = key;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the key
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

// Function to simulate mouse click
void SimulateMouseClick(bool isRight = true)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dwFlags = isRight ? MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN : MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    input.mi.dwFlags = isRight ? MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP : MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

// Function to move mouse relatively
void MoveMouse(int dx, int dy)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = dx;
    input.mi.dy = dy;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

// Main function and loop
int main()
{

    // Auth::init("redacted :) (its a pastebin auth lmfao)");

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, _T(" "), NULL };
    ::RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_CAPTION ^ WS_THICKFRAME ^ WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 100, 100, width, height, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);

    // Initialize Direct3D
    if (!CreateDeviceD3D(hwnd))
    {
        CleanupDeviceD3D();
        ::UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);
        return 1;
    }

    // Show the window
    ::ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    ::UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;

    SetupImGuiStyle();
    LoadSystemFont();

    ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(hwnd);
    ImGui_ImplDX11_Init(g_pd3dDevice, g_pd3dDeviceContext);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            continue;
        }

        ImGui_ImplDX11_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplWin32_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        RenderMenu();
        Update();
        ImGui::Render();
        const float clear_color_with_alpha[4] = { 0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f };
        g_pd3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_mainRenderTargetView, nullptr);
        g_pd3dDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_mainRenderTargetView, clear_color_with_alpha);
        ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        g_pSwapChain->Present(1, 0);
    }

    ImGui_ImplDX11_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplWin32_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    CleanupDeviceD3D();
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);

    return 0;
}

cl.exe command
cl /std:c++17 /EHsc /FeYourProgramName.exe main.cpp imgui.cpp imgui_draw.cpp imgui_widgets.cpp imgui_tables.cpp imgui_impl_dx11.cpp imgui_impl_win32.cpp /link d3d11.lib d3dcompiler.lib user32.lib Dwmapi.lib

g++ command
g++ main.cpp imgui.cpp imgui_draw.cpp imgui_widgets.cpp imgui_tables.cpp imgui_impl_dx11.cpp imgui_impl_win32.cpp -o your_program -lgdi32 -ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler

These are the core snippets of code for the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

There is not a shred of useful information in this post. No code, no command line for cl.exe, no error messages, nothing. What exactly do you expect us to do with it?

sorry bout that, I have added some code snippets.
